# File not found error (a file located on WSL) on python platform

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, odoo

I'm working on Odoo project, and it's located on wsl of my windows OS, so when I build the project and go to specific route, it gives me an error like:

`\\wsl$\ubuntu-20.04\home\abdulghani\odoo_community\odoo17\addons\auth_ldap\README.rst`

But when I put this path on windows explorer it gives me a correct location and open the file, so how python handle absolute paths when building the project

The error is located here:

```py
 if normalized_path.startswith('addons' + os.sep):
        normalized_path = normalized_path[7:]

    for addons_dir in addons_paths:
        # final path sep required to avoid partial match
        parent_path = os.path.normpath(os.path.normcase(addons_dir)) + os.sep
        fpath = (normalized_path if is_abs else
                 os.path.normpath(os.path.normcase(os.path.join(parent_path, normalized_path))))
        if fpath.startswith(parent_path) and os.path.exists(fpath):
            return fpath

    raise FileNotFoundError("File not found: " + file_path)
```

Comment: \ is not a path separator in Linux. Also, no code where this path is generated ?

Comment: I used both "\" and "/" and isn't working at all